# How to implement "split" function in iOS

Tags: ios, sdk

how to implement such function?[image]

the steps are the following,
(1) press a button or something
(2) the screen separate two parts and show its content.

### I am new on iOS programming, I don't know what's the function called, and seek some resources to learn. Thanks.

PS:
if I want to code by myself, what should I learning, for example, core animation or something?

Comment: Hi iAsk, 

This may not be directive enough, but you may have an interest in [JWFolders](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/jwfolders)

Comment: hi  Disruptive Art， thanks very much. I have tried. It's very good resource to learn. please post your answer again and I will mark it as  correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JWFolders](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/jwfolders) may be helpful in getting the stuff you need. Just like Tigeuro said [Cocoa Controls](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls) is a really good resource.

Have fun with it, Objective-C is a fun language to tinker with.

Comment: With storyboards, is it possible to use segue to mimic the same effect all with in the storyboard (no need for an xib)?

Comment: maybe I'm wrong, but you can't implement it with a segue since segues are meant to replace the current scene.

Comment: I suggest taking a look through the Cocoa Controls site and see if they have something you are thinking of doing or a starting point for you to build on.

Answer (score 3):

you should also take a look at this:
http://www.merowing.info/2012/07/pinch-to-reveal-animation-like-in-boeing-milestones/

Answer (score 1):

It is not part of iOS API but [Cocoa Controls](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls): is your friend usually in that case. You will find there a third party implementations like [RECurtainViewController](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/recurtainviewcontroller) and [JWFolders](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/jwfolders) which are closed to what you are willing to achieve. I don't think this is too hard: you need a basic understanding of how views operates and some basic core data knowledge will do.

Comment: you are right. I need some idea to rich my experience. thanks a lot for your reference. very useful.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the official API to do this. You might find 3rd party implementations on the web.

If you cannot find then you will have to code it yourself.